# random DateTime over a definite range

Tags: java, date, random, time, range

Hi looking for a sample code which will return a RandomDateTime as  1968-02-03 23:02:03 over a range (1960,1970).

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

my code is returning timezone in between which I don't want. 
...

Comment: can you provide code that youve already attempted?

Comment: In what language? JavaScript? Python? C#? COBOL?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean that you don’t want time zone. Each time zone has its own setting the clock forward and backward between 1960 and 1970, so if you don’t take time zone into account, you risk getting a non-existing time.

Comment: If you are tracking moments, specific points on the timeline, you should be applying a time zone. By ignoring time zones, you have only a date and a time-of-day. So "noon on the 23rd of January 2020" could be noon in Tokyo Japan, or noon in Toulouse France or noon in Toledo Ohio US — three very different moments occurring several hours apart.

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    LocalDateTime minInclusive = LocalDateTime.of(1960, Month.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0);
    LocalDateTime maxExclusive = LocalDateTime.of(1971, Month.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0);

    int seconds = Math.toIntExact(ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(minInclusive, maxExclusive));
    int choice = rand.nextInt(seconds);
    LocalDateTime randomDateTime = minInclusive.plusSeconds(choice);
    System.out.println(randomDateTime);
```

Example output (from running just now):

> 1960-12-05T19:05:28

I am using `LocalDateTime` because you said you wanted no time zone, but you risk getting a non-exisitng time, typically a time in the spring gap when the clocks are turned forward when sumer time (DST) begins. To avoid this risk, use `ZonedDateTime` and specify the time zone. The code will be very similar to the above.

Calling [`between`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html#between(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.Temporal)) on [`ChronoUnit.SECONDS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#SECONDS) calculates elapsed time as whole seconds.

The call to [`Math.toIntExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact(long)) is a safer way to go from a 64-bit `long` to an 32-bit `int`. Throws an exception if the value overflows.

The output from printing `randomDateTime` is in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. If you want a different format (for example, without the `T` in the middle), you may format it using a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). [Search for how](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20DateTimeFormatter&t=osx&ia=web).

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use *java.time*.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Randon date using ThreadLocalRandom class.
Here is quick fix for you. Please check following code.

**Input :**

Enter the Start Date: dd/mm/yyyy

01/01/1960

Enter the End Date: dd/mm/yyyy

01/01/1970

**Output :**

1969-04-18 06:30:54

```
        Scanner input = null;
        try {
            input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the Start Date: dd/mm/yyyy");
            String begin = new String();
            begin = input.nextLine();
            SimpleDateFormat startFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
            Date startDate = startFormat.parse(begin);

            System.out.println("Enter the End Date: dd/mm/yyyy");
            String end = new String();
            end = input.nextLine();
            SimpleDateFormat endFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
            Date endDate = endFormat.parse(end);

            Date randomDate = new Date(ThreadLocalRandom.current()
                    .nextLong(startDate.getTime(), endDate.getTime()));

            String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
            String randomDateFormat = simpleDateFormat.format(randomDate);
            System.out.println(randomDateFormat);

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            input.close();
        }
```

Hope this solution works.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.